# #SNMP - GetBulk V2 request is limited to 100 results?

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp

I'm trying to perform the below request and the results should be around 900 variables, not 100.
it doesn't matter how many oids I send 1 or 10, I always get no more than 100 variables.
what I'm doing wrong?

```
            var readCommunity = new OctetString("XXXXX");
            var oidsList = new List<string>
            {
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14",
"1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6"
            };
            var oids = oidsList.Select(oid => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(oid))).ToArray();
            
            ISnmpMessage request= new GetBulkRequestMessage(
                0,
                VersionCode.V2,
                readCommunity,
                0,
                1000,
                oids);

            var response = request.GetResponse(60000, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("1.1.1.1"), 161));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a request asking for as many items as you wished, but it is the agent who decides how many to return to you. That's how the standard defines,

> The receiving SNMP entity produces a Response-PDU with **up to the
> total number of requested variable bindings** communicated by the
> request.

> While the maximum number of variable bindings in the Response-PDU is
> bounded by N + (M * R), the response may be generated with **a lesser
>
> number of variable bindings (possibly zero)** for either of three
> reasons.

[Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#page-14)